# flashing background

Tags: android, animation

I have a `LinearLayout` with a few `Buttons` and `TextViews`. I want my background to flash at timed intervals, say from red to white to red and so on.  Right now, I am trying this code, but it gives me a null pointer exception.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(50); 
anim.setStartOffset(20);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
ll.startAnimation(anim); // shows null pointer exception at this line
```

Please help me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please attach the logcat.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have specified the wrong `View` id here `findViewById(R.layout.activity_main)`. It should be something like:

```
findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
```

Also, make sure to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` right after `super.onCreate`

**EDIT**:

Here is the code that allows you to change only the background color with any colors you want. It looks like [`AnimationDrawable.start()` doesn't work if called from `Activity.onCreate`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1818), so we have to use `Handler.postDelayed` here.

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
final AnimationDrawable drawable = new AnimationDrawable();
final Handler handler = new Handler();

drawable.addFrame(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED), 400);
drawable.addFrame(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN), 400);
drawable.setOneShot(false);

layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        drawable.start();
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: thanks :) works now... can u help me with setting colors to the animation? also, is it possible that my buttons n textviews do not blink and just the background part does?

Comment: when i use this, it just sets the background color to red. no animation. also, `layout.setBackground` is undefined for type linear layout. eclipse gives 3 fixes- `setBackgroundColor()`, `setBackgroundDrawable()` and `setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: ooops, it should be `setBackgroundDrawable`. if you have no any animation make sure to call `drawable.start()`. Pleast note, that it **must** be called **after** calling `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: i called drawable.start() still it shows just the red background screen

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated, use `ViewCompat.setBackground(layout,drawable);` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(50); 
anim.setStartOffset(20);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
ll.startAnimation(anim);
```

and If `activity_main` is your XML file name then

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and use your layout id here

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id);
```